# Test if two items in a set are found in a list element

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop, set

I have a set of two values called mySet. It looks something like this:

```
mySet = {1010101, 20202030}
```

And I have a list, myList, of lines that contain four strings each. A line in the list looks something like this:

```
1 1010101 20202030 15.3
```

with each of the four strings separated by a single space. I would like to construct a loop where if both of the values in mySet are contained in a single line of myList, the loop will return TRUE. I have an idea that maybe I could make a new list of just the second and third elements of each line of myList and then check the values from mySet against that, but I'm not sure how I would implement that either. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You should have a go at the problem yourself, and then if you can't solve it, show your code and let us help fix a specific problem.

Comment: Aside: `mySet = ([1010101, 20202030])` creates a list (from the brackets `[]`; the parentheses do nothing), not a set.  Possibly you forgot `set`, as in `set([1010101, 20202030])`, although `{1010101, 20202030}` would also work.

Comment: Is each line a string?  If your problem that you don't know how to extract the four substrings, have a look at str.split.  Type `help(str.split)` in the shell.

Comment: You probably want a function, not a loop.  Loops don't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "return" you meant a function (or any callable), you need to do so separately despite the `for` loop, because `for` loops don't return anything.

However, this problem can be easily solved with the builtin [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) functions like this:

```
mySet = {str(i) for i in {1010101, 20202030}}
myList = ["1 1010101 20202030 15.3"]

result = any(all(s in l for s in mySet) for l in myList)

print(result)
```

It will print `True`. We have done all of the calculation in one single line. Also, notice how I converted all the integers in to strings in the mySet - you might want to do it separately in another set, if you don't want to mutate that set.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in myList:
    print(mySet.issubset(map(float, line.split(" "))))
```

[split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) to convert space-separated values to list

[map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to convert all list elements to floats for comparison

[issubset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) (or equivalently issuperset) to check whether one is a [subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) of the other